# save with signals on same model on django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I would like to merge these methods on figure_1 so i can get the figure_2 and use signals to save the results on the same model. something is wrong so results are not saved on the model

figure_1 :

```
class Invoice(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    amount_gtotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    amount_gtax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    amount_gamount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def amount_gtotal(self):
        items = self.invoiceitem_set.all()
        amount_gtotal = 0.00
        for item in items:
            amount_gtotal += item.price * item.quantity
        return amount_gtotal

    def amount_gtax(self):
        items = self.invoiceitem_set.all()
        amount_gtax = 0
        for item in items:
            amount_gtax += item.price_sell * item.quantity * item.vat
        return amount_gtax

    def amount_gamount(self):
        amount_gamount = self.amount_gtotal() + self.amount_gtax()
        return amount_gamount
```

figure_2 :

```
    def calculate(self):

        invoiceitems = self.invoiceitem_set.all()

        amount_gtotal = 0
        amount_gtax = 0
        amount_gamount = 0

        for invoiceitem in invoiceitems:
            amount_gtotal += item.price * item.quantity
            amount_gtax += item.price_sell * item.quantity * item.vat
            amount_gamount += amount_gtotal + amount_gtax

        totals = {
            'amount_gtotal': amount_gtotal,
            'amount_gtax': amount_gtax,
            'amount_gamount': amount_gamount,
        }

        for k,v in totals.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
            if save == True:
                self.save()
        return totals

def invoice_pre_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.calculate()

pre_save.connect(invoice_pre_save, sender=Invoice)


class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey('Invoice', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price_sell = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    vat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

I would like to merge these methods on figure_1 so i can get the figure_2 and use signals to save the results on the same model. something is wrong so results are not saved on the model

Comment: In fact, calculate func should retun a variable not defined <save> I have posted a possible solution, chek it out!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass in the calculate func a default parameter for save variable, like this:

```
def calculate(self, save=False):
```

Then in signal func  you can pass again save, like this:

```
def invoice_pre_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.calculate(save=False)

pre_save.connect(invoice_pre_save, sender=Order)
```

And now you should be able to call calulate(save=True)

Comment: i tried it, but half solution, when i create an invoice, it doesn t save the values on their fields, but i update the invoice without any changes, it update it and values on table are updated too

Comment: Maybe you need to try to change that <item> var's in calculate func, adn use <invoiceitem> instead.